# Can I use actionResulting to link Questionnaire to a CarePlan activity?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have asked about [Questionnaire and CarePlan earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348567/access-and-scheduling-of-fhir-questionnaire-resource) and someone else has asked another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395627/reference-to-fhir-questionnaire-in-diagnosticorder-or-careplan), but my question this time is a bit more specific.

This time I wonder if it's allowed to create a CarePlan using 'detail' rather than reference and then link Questionnaire in to actionResulting. Could I use the actionResulting as a link to the Questionnaire? Would the following resource be valid?

```
{
  "resourceType": "CarePlan",
  ...,
  "activity": [
    {
      "actionResulting": [
        {
          "reference": "Questionnaire/copd-form"
        }
      ]
      "detail": {
        "category": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/care-plan-activity-category",
              "code": "observation"
            }
          ]
        },
        "code": {
          "text": "A code for capturing COPD subjective input from patient?"
        },
        "prohibited": false,
        "scheduledTiming": {
          "repeat": {
            "frequency": 1,
            "period": 1,
            "periodUnits": "d"
          }
        },
        "performer": [
          {
            "reference": "Patient/3183"
          }
        ],
        "description": "Daily COPD form"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pointing to the Questionnaire would be saying "as a result of this plan, this Questionnaire was designed".  I suspect what you'd really want to say is "as a result of this plan, I asked the patient to fill out Questionnaire X" (which would be a DiagnosticOrder) or "as a result of this plan, the patient answered this Questionnaire" (which would be a QuestionnaireResponse).  For the first of those, I believe we're still waiting on an extension to allow a DiagnosticRequest to point to the Questionnaire to be filled out.

Comment: OK, so there'd be no way of linking in the Questoinnaire directly into the CarePlan. The desired process is to create DiagnosticOrder with an extension to link to Questionnaire, and then use 'reference' in CarePlan to reference to this. I would then NOT fill in 'details' in careplan, as DiagnosticOrder would have these details instead.

Comment: For simplicity it would have been nice in my case to avoid creating DiagnosticOrder as a separate resource. But maybe it's fine when I think about it a bit... I may submit a change request just to have a discussion on it.

Comment: A Questionnaire is a type of "definition".  We could potentially add an extension to CarePlan.action.detail that allows referencing the "protocol" or definition associated with the action to be completed.  It would be appropriate for that to point to Questionnaire.  (And eventually point to the OrderSet or Protocol resource or whatever we end up calling it.)  Feel free to propose that as a change request.