# How to schedule questionnaires with hapi-fhir Java API?

Tags: scheduler, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

My question seems similar to [Access and scheduling of FHIR Questionnaire resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32348567/1326692) but I have something different to get understanding

As per my understanding with fhir supports many complex data types to support scheduling events. I came across many such types including `Timing`, `Period`, `Schedule`, `CarePlan` and `CarePlanActivityDetailComponent` So I can manage to store my frequency settings somehow with above types but I can't understand how will actual scheduler work?

Does fhir supports to schedule events and provide event notifications based on scheduler settings (like weekly every Monday 10 AM)? If yes, is there any simple reference example where we can see usage for scheduling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FHIR is a data exchange standard.  Schedule allows you to share a particular Practitioner or Location's schedule (what time slots they have available).  You can then create Appointment instances to occupy those slots.  You can use Subscription to receive notifications when data changes.  You can also schedule events (therapy, patient communications, medications, etc.) to occur at a particular frequency (using the ServiceRequest, CommunicationRequest and MedicationRequest resources respectively).  But FHIR is not a general timing service for sending system-level events.

PS(for beginner) : Read first three comments for better understanding

Comment: Hi @Lloyd, Thanks a lot for your response. It's useful but I can't understand one thing. You mentioned we can schedule events (therapy, patient communications, medications, etc.) to occur at a particular frequency. So without timing service how this scheduling will work?

Comment: If I write a prescription that says "Take one tablet once a day at 7pm" - that's enough for exchange.  A patient might set an alarm on their phone.  The nursing application in a hospital might automatically include the med in those to be taken with supper, etc.  How a system or individual determines that something happens according to the desired timing is outside the scope of the data exchange - and thus outside the scope of FHIR.

Comment: Hi @Lloyd : I understood now, thanks for clarifying very nicely